# How to set tag of select in proper way to have the size of "5"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you see in the snippet below , there are many options .
When I click the select tagment , a long list will appear before it become the size of 5 . You can try it . I don't want the wrong effect of it .

I tried mousedown event to prevent it  but failed . How to controll it ?

```js
$("#select").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   if ( !$(this).hasClass("size") ) {
    $(this).attr("size","5");
    $(this).addClass("size");
   } else {
    $(this).attr("size","1");
    $(this).removeClass("size");
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
   <select name="test" id="select">
    asdfasdf
    <option value="">option1</option>
    <option value="">option2</option>
    <option value="">option3</option>
    <option value="">option4</option>
    <option value="">option5</option>
    <option value="">option6</option>
    <option value="">option7</option>
    <option value="">option8</option>
    <option value="">option9</option>
    <option value="">option8</option>
    <option value="">option7</option>
    <option value="">option6</option>
    <option value="">option5</option>
    <option value="">option4</option>
    <option value="">option3</option>
    <option value="">option2</option>
    <option value="">option1</option>
    <option value="">option2</option>
    <option value="">option3</option>
    <option value="">option4</option>
    <option value="">option5</option>
    <option value="">option6</option>
    <option value="">option7</option>
    <option value="">option8</option>
    <option value="">option9</option>
    <option value="">option0</option>
    <option value="">option9</option>
    <option value="">option8</option>
    <option value="">option7</option>
    <option value="">option6</option>
   </select>
  </div>
```

It can't become the size of one when blur.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to achieve. What is the goal?

Comment: what should be your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   $("#test").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).focus();
    if ( $("option").length > 5 ) {
     //选项超过五个
     if ( !$(this).hasClass("size") ) {
      //未打开状态时 展开下拉列表
      $(this).attr("size","5").addClass("size");
     } else {
      //已打开状态时 收回下拉列表
      $(this).attr("size","1").removeClass("size").blur();
     }
    } else {
     //选项不超过五个
     if ( !$(this).hasClass("size") ) {
      //未打开状态时 展开下拉列表
      $(this).attr("size" , $("option").length).addClass("size");
     } else {
      //已打开状态时 收回下拉列表
      $(this).attr("size","1").removeClass("size").blur();
     }
    }
   }).mousedown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   }).blur(function(){
    $(this).attr("size","1").removeClass("size");
   }).change(function(){
    //blur之后才会触发change
    console.log($("option:selected").html());
   });
   $("option").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).index());
    $("option").eq($(this).index()).prop("selected","selected");
   });


  });
```

```css
#test{
  font-size: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select name="test" id="test" >
  asdfasdf
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd2</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd3</option>
  <option value="">asdfasfd4</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#select").one("click",function(){
   if (!$("#select").hasClass("size")) {
     $("#select").attr("size", "5");
     $("#select").addClass("size");
   } else {
     $("#select").attr("size", "1");
     $("#select").removeClass("size");
   }
});
```

Comment: sorry , but it doesn't help

Comment: Nope . It should have one by default but when I click it , it will have size of 5

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on another post the other day it had a good link to a working fiddle using jquery.

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=2;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aTzc2/

You can just set the this.size= to whatever you want.

```
<div id="myselect-container">
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=5;">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
    <option value="7">option 7</option>
    <option value="8">option 8</option>
    <option value="9">option 9</option>
    <option value="10">option 10</option>
    <option value="11">option 11</option>
        <option value="12">option 12</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css:

```
#myselect-container {
    position:relative;
    height:9px;
    width:100px;
    /*for contain our absoulte select tag */
}
#myselect-container select {
   position:absolute;
   /*for put our list on other tag */
```

}

Comment: Awesome ! But there is a little bug : when I click the tagment (not triangle) the second time it doesn't show as expected .

Comment: Is this for a specific browser? I don't see the bug in chrome.

Comment: Also in chrome . First step : click "is" and select the second option ; Second Step : click "is" again to change the option . Try again if there occur something wrong

Comment: I must be missing something. So your steps are:
1) Click select box
2) Select Option 2
3) Click select box

Result (using my fiddle) it doesn't show limited number of select options? Or is the issue happening inside of your code?

Comment: I updated my answer to have the exact code (minus whatever options you want to use) I have tested the fiddle, when I select an option, and then go back to select another option it only shows 5. If you select 6 for instance it will show 2-6. Don't forget to use the css in the fiddle. If you are still having issues can you upload a screenshot of your error to somewhere (like http://prnt.sc/) so I can better understand the problem?